# Multivariate Variational Autoencoder and Positive Definite Covariance Matrix

Tags: autoencoders

This might be a naive question from a non-statistician but here we go. I understand that the challenges that hamper the use multivariate variational encoder where a covariance matrix is used instead of the a vector of standard deviation revolves around the increased number of parameters, lack of assurance of differentiability, and ensuring positive definiteness of the covariance matrix as explained [Variational Autoencoder and Covariance Matrix](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/388620/variational-autoencoder-and-covariance-matrix). However, couldn't a kernel/covariance function be parameterized using outputs of a deep learning model to overcome at least the differentiability and positive difiniteness issues? Why/why not?